# C - function and array

Tags: c, arrays

i have this code: `Link in the comments, could put here`
trying to make a sum function, that is at the top, ok, its working, but i'm having trouble to pass to my array.

function prototype:

```
int calc(char vetor[]){
```

i'm doing something like this:

```
int result = calc(out);
```

at my calc function, i return an int, catched from an array.
this is my function:

```
    for(i=0;i<strlen(vetor);i++){
   if(vetor[i] == '+'){
        aux = i-1;
        //reads what is behind +
        while((vetor[aux] >= '0') && (vetor[aux] <= '9')){
            auxSum1 += atoi(&vetor[aux]);
            aux--;
        }
        //Aux = i+1 to read the next +
        aux = i+1;

        while((vetor[aux] >= '0') && (vetor[aux] <= '9')){
            //reads what is in front of +

            auxSoma2 += atoi(&vetor[aux]); 
          aux++;
        }

        //return result sum
        resSoma = auxSoma2 + auxSoma1;

    }
return resSoma+resSub;
```

i have this for - and +.
At the end, i return the result of all the operations. if - dont exist, sum +0.

and i have an out array, that handle my cells, like this.

```
1   2   3   4
1   1+2 3   4
```

handle all the values, from cells.

after i return the calc to result, i try to make the result an array.

```
int result = calcular(out);
sprintf(out, "%d", result);
```

but when i print all the things, like this example, its happens:

```
0   0   0   0   
0   3   0   0
```

what i'm doing wrong?
when i have strings (test for exemple) appears 0.

What is wrong?
thanks

Comment: It'd be great if you could change comments/names to english. I'm happy to help, but I don't speak portuguese

Comment: Formatting the code properly would help readability too..

Comment: `auxSoma1 += atoi(&vetor[aux]);` - `vetor[aux]` is a `char`, unless you want to turn the entire rest of your string into a number instead of that particular character, this isn't what you want to do.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths vetor is a char, that has numbers inside, if i use atoi, i will not "use" this numbers?

Comment: can you add the function prototype?

Comment: is there a problem with processing when the `calc` does not include the operator?

Comment: probably...the problem is when we have or strings (letters) or single numbers (1,2,3,4,5)...

Comment: @GoldenMedal: `atoi()` takes a string. You're passing it the address of one character, which it will take as the start of a string. It'll read that one character and all the ones after it until it finds a character that is not a digit (or reaches the end of the string) and turn everything it has into a number. If this is what you want to happen, then it'll work, but since you're stepping through your string one character at a time, I'm assuming that it isn't. If you want to convert a single `char` to an number, subtract `'0'` from it, this is guaranteed to work in C.

Comment: i was thinkin in:
read the caracters behind + and in front of and SUM them, to obtain the result, that i will put into the cell...use only the normal aux += vetor[i] will not work?

Comment: `aux += vetor[i] - '0';` will work if you just want the value of a single digit. But that's not your issue, it's that your function only does anything when you have a `+` sign, looks like you forgot to write the rest of it.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

`if(vetor[i] == '+')`

Your function doesn't do anything when you don't find a `+` sign. That's why you're just getting that 3 in your output. It adds up the 1 and the 2 where you have `1+2`, but does nothing for all your other numbers, because they don't have `+` signs in them.

You should just look for a number, first, and use `strtol()` to get a pointer to the next character. Then, if it's not `NULL`, look for a plus sign, and if you find one, get the next number and add them. If you don't, just return the first number you found.

Other than that, you've only posted some of your function, so we can't tell what the rest is doing. You're missing a brace at the end, and we can't see where you define `resSoma` or `resSub`, so impossible to tell what your final `return` statement is doing.

Comment: i tryied my best, never saw strlol, but i tryied my best. Like this?http://pastebin.com/RJTgVP4E

Comment: No, not really. I'm trying to help, but really, I can't teach you basic C on SO. I'd suggest going through a good tutorial book, it'll help you to get the hang of things like this.